# How Pppoe subscriber with static ip sends ipcp request

Tags: ipv4, dhcp, pppoe

How a pppoe subscriber with static ip sends ipcp configure request.  For dhcp the subscriber can include 0.0.0.0 in configure request of ipcp packet and obtain its ip from remote server. But in static ip case, will it work only if subcriber always sends its fixed ip?  Can ipcp support static ip like dhcp?

Comment: Depends on the ISP setup. Some will always return the static address no matter what you ask for -- zero or the actual address. Others will only return the static if asked for. (Bellsouth used to require `%static` on the username to activate one's static address)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

IPCP for PPPoE is the same as with serial PPP - check [RFC 1332](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1332).

A peer sends a *Configure-Request* (type 3) containing the desired IP address which the other side then either *Configure-Ack*s or *Configure-Nak*s. The address `0.0.0.0` requests any address.